# Can I split up app.yaml into multiple files?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

In my Python App Engine project my app.yaml file is getting quite long with all the /handlers I've added.

Is there a way to break this file into separate files so I can easily organize/manage them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can with `includes` statement. Create .yaml files for each handlers and in your app.yaml, mention them using `includes`

From official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig):

The following example shows included .yaml files, with handlers defined there instead of inside the app.yaml file that includes those other .yaml files:

```
includes:
- cloud_endpoints.yaml
- web_interface.yaml
- admin_interface.yaml
```

The included .yaml files would have the handlers directly defined under `handlers:` element.

Comment: I don't know how I missed this or if it was added recently.  Regardless thanks for the link.